# How to find g(x) and aux function h(x) when doing fixed point interation?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I'm learning fixed point iteration (first and second form).

My teacher said there are two forms:

```
g(x) = x - f(x)
g(x) = x - h(x)f(x)
```

where `h(x)` is an aux function.

suppose `f(x) = x^2 + 2x -3`.

Let `f(x) = 0`.

```
x^2 + 2x -3 = 0
x^2  = - 2x + 3
x = 3/x -2
```

So we let `g(x) = 3/x -2`, for a fixed point, and root, right?

To solve, we iterate and see convergence:

```
xk+1 = 3/xk -2
```

and pick an initial `xk`.

My teacher said that in second form:

from `f(x) = x^2 + 2x -3`:

```
g(x) = (x + (x^2 + 2x -3)) / (x^2 - 5)
```

with the aux function `h(x) = -1 / (x^2 - 5)`

Where did he get `h(x) = -1 / (x^2 - 5)` from? And where is

```
g(x) = (x + (x^2 + 2x -3)) / (x^2 - 5)
```

from?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> My teacher said that in second form: from `f(x) = x^2 + 2x -3`:
>
> [one could consider]   `g(x) = (x + (x^2 + 2x -3)) / (x^2 - 5)`
>
> with the aux[iliary] function `h(x) = -1 / (x^2 - 5)`
>
> Where did he get `h(x) = -1 / (x^2 - 5)` from? And where is
>
> `g(x) = (x + (x^2 + 2x -3)) / (x^2 - 5)`
>
> [coming] from?

This is most probably not what they said, and it seems that typos due to carelessness are killing you here.

Actually, to solve $f(x)=0$ with $f(x)=x^2 + 2x -3$, they most probably suggested to solve $g(x)=x$ with $$g(x) = x + \frac{x^2 + 2x -3}{x^2 - 5}$$ that is, a function $g$ exactly of the general form $g(x)=x-f(x)h(x)$, for the auxiliary function $$h(x) = -\frac1{x^2 - 5}$$ They chose $h$ arbitrarily.

---

**Supplementary material:** This choice of auxiliary function $h$ is not especially suited to this precise function $f$, if you ask me. A better choice would be to get rid of the $x^2$ term in $f(x)$, using $$g_c(x)=x-\frac{x^2 + 2x -3}{x+c}$$ for some fixed positive $c$, that is, $g_c(x)=x-f(x)h_c(x)$ with $$h_c(x)=\frac1{x+c}$$ Now, a simple computation shows that $$g_c(x)=\frac{(c-2)x+3}{x+c}$$ hence the value $c=2$ is interesting, leading to the iteration of the function $$g_2(x)=\frac3{x+2}$$
Note finally that for every initial condition $x_0\geqslant0$, the sequence defined recursively by $x_{n+1}=g_2(x_n)$ converges to the positive root $x^*$ of $f$ at a geometric rate $\frac13$ (and that $x^*=1$, but this is irrelevant to the construction and to the remark).